# script to delete duplicate files using md5

Tags: bash, script, duplicate

I  want to write a script to find duplicate files in a given directory and delete the copy depending on the hashcode. When I run the script it deletes the copy and the original file.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1;
b=0;
c=1;

while true
do
echo "Enter the directory:"
read directory
if [ -d $directory ]; then
break
else
echo "Invalid directory"
fi
done

for FILE in `ls $directory`
do
b=`expr $b + $a`
if [ $b -gt 2 ]
then
h= `md5sum $directory/$FILE | awk '{ print $1 }'`
a=0;
for f in `ls $directory`
do
a=`expr $a + $c`
if [ $a -gt 2 ]
then
s= `md5sum $directory/$FILE | awk '{ print $1 }'`
if [ "$f" == "$FILE" ]
then
break
else
if [ "$s" = "$h" ]
then
rm -rf $directory/$FILE
fi
fi    
fi
done
fi
done
```

Comment: Please either get somebody else's well tested code for this, or read about [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution), indentation, and why [parsing `ls` output is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). This script is a death trap.

Comment: If you properly [indent your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) it will be easier to read. Remove the space after `h=` on line 22 and after `s=` on line 29. Use `$((b+a))` instead of `expr` to add `$a` and `$b`. Use e.g. `for f in "$directory/*"` instead of parsing `ls` output. Quote your variables. No need to mix between `[ = ]` and `[ == ]` — do you know the difference? *Edit:* I see that l0b0 was thinking along the same lines :-) .

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts takes the first file in the directory and compares against all files there, thus the first file is checked against itself. Which will return same MD5 hash. Because `$FILE` and `$f` are exactly the same. You should change the script for comparing files only and avoid comparing a file with itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  echo "Enter the directory:"
  read directory
  if [ -d $directory ]; then
    break
  else
    echo "Invalid directory"
  fi
done

for FILE in `ls $directory`
do
  if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
    break;
  fi
  h=`md5sum $directory/$FILE | awk '{ print $1 }'`
  for f in `ls $directory`
  do
    if [ -f $f ] && [ $FILE != $f ]; then
      s=`md5sum $directory/$f | awk '{ print $1 }'`
      if [ "$s" = "$h" ]; then
        echo Removing $f
        rm -rf $directory/$f
      fi
    fi
  done
done
```

That said, you can find two different files which throw the same MD5 hash. It's not common nor easy, but it's certainly not impossible. So this script could delete two different files "thinking" they have the same content.

A safer script would be this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  echo "Enter the directory:"
  read directory
  if [ -d $directory ]; then
    break
  else
    echo "Invalid directory"
  fi
done

for FILE in `ls $directory`
do
  if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
    break;
  fi
  for f in `ls $directory`
  do
    if [ -f $f ] && [ $FILE != $f ]; then
      cmp -s $directory/$FILE $directory/$f
      if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo Removing $f
        rm -rf $directory/$f
      fi
    fi
  done
done
```